# braintree How can I hold a payment for 24 hours?

Tags: php, braintree

I need to add $1 trial product, but instead of charging the $1, we just "authorize" it (temp hold of $1 -- looks like a charge to customer on their statement, but not charged yet)

Since many people, in offers like this, cancel right away after getting the first trial/cheap item:

if someone cancels their plan within 24 hours from their trial purchase, we remove the auth, do NOT charge them the dollar, and DO NOT send them anything

if they don't cancel, after 24 hours we finalize the $1 charge, fulfill their trial order.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by `archiving`? Can you update your question so that it meets [Stack Overflow guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)? Specifically, are there any error messages you are seeing or expected behavior that is not happening? Can you include any code to help us replicate your issue?

Comment: I've not tried anything yet, I was looking suggestions or ideas about this. Because I spent much time researching but I didn't find a possible solution. Could you give any suggestion, please?

Comment: @JessicaOlivo your question is pretty generalized for this forum. You might get better results reaching out to [Braintree Support](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/forms/contact) directly.